# when I start debugging on Intellij for some reason multiple unfamiliar java classes open up before I can start going through my break points

Tags: intellij-idea

[the 3 tabs on the upper right are the ones which I don't recognize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr9iX.png)
the 3 tabs on the upper right appear once I start going through the debugger(pressingf8) and I have to keep going through it with f8 until I finally reach the program I want to debug.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer:
[How to force IntelliJ to only step into my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724290/4326441)

You have to add classes you don't want to debug to ***Do not step into the classes*** list available in: *Settings/Preferences* -> *Debugger/Stepping*:
[image: Do not step into the classes]