# Why does Java Debugger steps into internal methods randomly?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

It's been some time since I started noticing that while debugging the application I'm working on, the java debugger randomly steps into some Spring Framework internal methods.

For example, when I add a breakpoint in a RestController endpoint method that calls another service method, the debugger steps into BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor.getPointcut() method.

This behavior makes me upset because the only way to avoid this is to add a breakpoint in the service method.

Does anyone know why this happens?

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2020.3 , Java 8 and Spring Boot 2.X if this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some classes in Spring are enhanced with aspects to provide orthogonal functionality (in this case: transactions, which probably means you annotated your method or class with `@Transactional`).

At run time (or compile time) additional code is weaved around your own code to provide that functionality (start transaction before running your code, committing on successful completion, or rolling back for (some) exceptions).

In other words, when your code runs, there is more code than just your own, and when you step through the debugger, IntelliJ will step through that code as well and show it to you.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Mark, do you know if it's possible to avoid this behavior somehow?

Comment: @Marcos Do you mean avoid those methods being there, or avoid them showing up in the debugger? The first,no, the second, maybe IntelliJ has some features for this, I'm not sure. See also [How to force IntelliJ to only step into my source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575107/how-to-force-intellij-to-only-step-into-my-source-code)

Comment: Woah, I knew I already searched for something along those lines before but I couldn't remember the exact terms to find it again, thank you! I think the second answer to that question is exactly what I'm looking for. 
Thanks Mark!